# Javascript not behaving as expected. Unable to identify cause.

Tags: javascript, html, css

in an attempt to make practical use of the skills I am learning on my web development course I am trying to create a website about the Vikings for my partner's Primary school class.

I have managed to get the HTML and CSS as I want it, but I'm struggling a little with the Javascript. it all looks fine to my mind but doesn't run as intended.

I have a quiz and a submit button. When clicked this button will reference a "checkresults" function in my .js file.

This should then calculate a result between 0 - 3 and post this result into the HTML page. I have designed the  box the results will show in to be invisible until the "Submit" button is clicked. However, when ran the results  box appears for only a second before disappearing and I cannot figure out why.

any help or advice would be very much appreciated!

//JAVASCRIPT//

```
function checkresults() {
var question1 = document.quiz.question1.value;
var question2 = document.quiz.question2.value;
var question3 = document.quiz.question3.value;
var correct = 0;
if (question1 == "793") {
correct++;
}
if (question2 == "Shield") {
correct++;
}
if (question3 == "1066") {
correct++;
}

var message = ["You're a real Viking!", "Not bad but you can do better!", 
"Odin would not be pleased with your effort!"];
var range;

if (correct < 1) {
range = 2;
}
if (correct > 0 && correct < 3) {
range = 1;
}
if (correct > 2) {
range = 0;
}

document.getElementById("afterSubmit").style.visibility = "visible"

document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message[ramge];
document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML = "You got " + correct + " 
correct!";
}

//HTML//
<form id="quiz" name="quiz">
<p>When did the Vikings first invade Britain?</p>
<input type="radio" id="mc" name="question1" value="1066" />1066<br />
<input type="radio" id="mc" name="question1" value="793" />793<br />
<input type="radio" id="mc" name="question1" value="411" />411<br />
<input type="radio" id="mc" name="question1" value="1999" />1999<br />

<p>what did every man need before he was allowed to go Viking?</p>
<input type="radio" id="mc" name="question2" value="Shield" />Shield<br />
<input type="radio" id="mc"name="question2" value="Sword" />Sword<br />
<input type="radio" id="mc"name="question2" value="Cloak" />Cloak<br />
<input type="radio" id="mc" name-"question2" value="Gold" />Gold<br />

<p>when did the Viking age end?</p>
<input type="radio" id="mc" name="question3" value="793" />793<br />
<input type="radio" id="mc" name="question3" value="1999" />1999<br />
<input type="radio" id="mc" name="question3" value="1066" />1066<br />
<input type="radio" id="mc" name="question3" value="1500" />1500<br />

<input type="submit" id="button" value="Lets see how you did!" onclick = 
"checkresults();">
</form>

<div id="afterSubmit">
<p id="message"></p>
<p id="correct"></p>

//CSS//
#afterSubmit {
visibility: hidden;
border-color: red;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
}
```

Comment: As a small comment unrelated to your question. In this case it's all fine, but in general, there's a difference between visibility: hidden and display: none. Usually you would use visibility: hidden to keep the element in you page (keeping structure/spacing intact)or when it's meant to be discoverable by screenreaders. Display:none suits your usage better in this case

Answer (score 2):

Your page is refreshing.

The best way to change this would be to move the function to the form onsubmit event.

```
//Remove the onclick
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Lets see how you did!" onclick="checkresults();">
```

Add the function and return false to the event on the form, so it cancels submission

```
//Add the onsubmit, notice the return false, so it cancels submission
<form id="quiz" name="quiz" onsubmit="checkresults();return false;">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

I've removed the "onclick"

    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Lets see how you did!">

the form opening tag also now reads:

    <form id="quiz" name="quiz" onsubmit="checkresults();return false;">

But it still isn't working. Forgive me for being dense if I misunderstood your advice :)

Comment: I transfered your code to a JSfiddle and it seems to have a few javascript errors, which means stuff isn't working properly. Your last two lines of javascript (the innerHtml ones), range is misspelled and the correct line, no enters are allowed inside string values. I also had to adjust the way the onsubmit is send, which might not be needed for you, but was required for jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n6788y0p/